# Find sequences of digits in long integers efficiently

Tags: python, performance, integer, pattern-matching, sequence

Is it possible to find a defined sequence in an integer without converting it to a string?
That is, is it possible to do some form of pattern matching directly on integers.
I have not thought of one but I keeping thinking there should be a mathematical way of doing this. That's not to say it is more efficient.

(edit) I actually what numbers that don't contain the sequences of digits I am looking for.

The integers will be large, at least 289 digits. The sequences to find could be anything, "123", "5"(there is a five), "66666"

I am interested in a general solution but if you would like to help with the acutal problem I am trying to sovle keep reading.

More specifically I am looking for repeating digits of length 4 ie 1324322223313 "2222".
I am staring with integers because I will be incrementing though consecutive integers unless I get to an integer with 4 length repeat then I would skip to the the next integer without the repeat. Also I don't what integers with digit larger that 4 ie 12322135 (it has a 5) would be excluded.

The problem might also be stated as.
Find all integers in the z = range(x,y) such that z[a] does not contain any repeating digits of length 4 and a digit larger than 4. The range(x,y) may be very large

(Edit) in response to the comment, Yes I would actually like to generate a list, the problem I have is that I am not sure how I could make a generator that satisfies all the conditions I have. Maybe I should think about this more, I agree it would be simpler, but it might be similar to a generator for prime numbers, there is no such generator.

Comment: It seems like what you actually want is a way to generate all such numbers, rather than a way to test if a number fits or not since this will be much more efficient, is this correct?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have a generator as opposed to a filter/sieve but if you have suggestions of how I could to this that would be great.

Comment: I'll point out that 289 digit integers are nearly useless in our universe.  It's a much larger number than the number of electrons in the universe. No architecture actually stores a number that large as a word or anything, so you're not really saving much time treating it as an integer versus a string.

Comment: @Triptych, the advantage of a number is that there is an order to them  and which among other things makes it easy to increment. Although true there is an order "sort" for strings. But you might be right, Am I saving anything as an integer as opposed to a string?

Comment: If you were to have a generator, where would it start?  You say the numbers have at least 289 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this class to have your generator of digits :-)

```
import math

class DecimalIndexing:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def __len__(self):
        return int(math.floor(math.log10(self.n)+1))
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if isinstance(i, slice):
            return [self[x] for x in range(i.start, i.stop, i.step or 1)]
        else:
            return (self.n/(10**i))%10
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in xrange(len(self)):
            yield self[i]
```

you can use it like this:

```
di = DecimalIndexing(31415927)
for i in xrange(len(di)):
    if di[i:i+4] == [9,5,1,4]:
        print "found"
```

or like this:

```
for i in xrange(len(di)):
    if di[i:i+3] == [di[i]]*3:
        print "group of three equal digits at," i
```

or like this:

```
if 5 in di:
    print "has a five"
```

or like this:

```
if any(x > 5 in di):
    print "some digit was greater than five"
```

etc.

Keep in mind that the digits indices are "reversed", i.e. read from right to left.

Answer (score 1):

A list of digits is pretty simple.

```
# given n, a long integer
digits = [] 
while n != 0:
    digits.append( n%10 )
    n //= 10
digits.reverse()
```

You can then do your pattern matching on this list of digits.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: interesting solution to geting the integer to a list. I not sure this is better than str(n) and the pattern matching on that. Is it possible to do patter matching directly on integers? I guess I get better at asking my question as I read comments and solutions

Comment: Isn't the simpler way to get a list of digits in the string just list(str(n)) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make an iterator with the digits ordered from left to right this way

```
>>> import math
>>> number = int(123456789012345678901)
>>> #Get the maximum power of 10 using a logarithm
>>> max_digit = int(math.log10(number))
>>> range_pow = xrange(max_digit, 0, -1)
>>> # pot is an iterator with 1000, 100, 10, 1...
>>> pot = ( 10**x for x in range_pow)
>>> #Get the digits one by one on an iterator
>>> digits = ( (number/x)%10 for x in pot )
>>> l = list(digits)
>>> print l
[1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 0L]
```

Then you can check if the sequence is present... I'm looking for a easy way to do that through the iterator, something like a state machine to parse the result, but I'm not sure if there's a built-in way to do it without making a list or making the finite state machine by yourself...

You can go with something like this, but I think it will kill the performance (compared with a finite state parsing done on low level over the iterator) as you need to build the list, not working directly with iterator:

```
>>> print l
[1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 0L]
>>> find = [1,2,3]
>>> lf = len(find)
>>> for i in xrange(len(l)):
...     if find == l[i:i+lf]:
...          print 'Found!', i
Found! 1
Found! 11
```

**Edited:**
I've come with a more iterative way to do things... The digits parameter could be
refined to create a list from a number, if necessary.

```
import math
from itertools import count

def find_digits_in_number(digits, number):
    #Get the maximum power of 10 using a logarithm
    max_digit = int(math.log10(number))
    range_pow = xrange(max_digit, -1, -1)
    # pot is an iterator with 1000, 100, 10, 1...
    pot = (10 ** x for x in range_pow)
    #Get the digits one by one on an iterator
    dig = ((number / x) % 10 for x in pot)

    #Current will store a moving windows with the 
    #size of the digits length to check if present
    current = []
    for i in digits:
        current.append(next(dig))

    digits = list(digits) 

    founds = []
    #The basic loop is this...
    #for digit, i in zip(dig, count()):
    #    if current == digits:
    #        founds.append(i)
    #    current.pop(0)
    #    current.append(digit)

    #But it can also be optimized like this list comprehension, 
    #while it's much less readable            
    [ (founds.append(i) if current == digits else None,\
      current.pop(0), current.append(digit)) \
      for digit, i in zip(dig, count()) ]

    #Check last posibility, with the last values
    if current == digits:
        founds.append(i + 1)

    return founds


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert find_digits_in_number((3, 4, 5), 123456789012345678901) == [2, 12]
    assert find_digits_in_number((3, 4), 123456789034) == [2, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to take a look here: [Cyclic Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number); they also have an algorithm to build a cyclic number.

This can be useful too: [Cycle detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd's_cycle-finding_algorithm#Tortoise_and_hare)

Answer (score 0):

@Fortran gives a great solution, it is very versatile.

I asked a modified version of this question on mathoverflow.net, They didn't seem to like the question, but I got a great answer. It answers a slightly different question but useful for my application.

To test if the digits 4444 are in 35344442345321456754 and assuming I know where I what to look for them then this is a nice solution and obvious once you see it.

```
(35344442345321456754 / 10**13) % 10**4 == 4444
```